# compare two list are same or not in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to compare two lists if the list before #\tab or before #\space are the same return true. not same return false. Here is the effort I try to do..I try to use recursion to solve the problem but I don't know where i am wrong.. (I am not allowed to use equal? i can only use char=?) my code always return false

```
(same? '(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o #\tab #\W #\o #\r #\l #\d)
     '(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o))
    => #t
    (same? '(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o #\space #\W #\o #\r #\l #\d)
     '(#\W #\o #\r #\l #\d))
    => #f  





     (define same?
(lambda (L1 L2)
(cond
((char=? (car L1) (car L2)) (same? (cdr L1) (cdr L2) ))
((char=? #\space (car L1)) #t)
((char=? #\tab (car L1)) #t)
((char=? #\newline (car L1)) #t)
(else #f)
)))
```

Comment: So you consider `(same? '() '()) ; ==> #f`, and `(same? '(#\H #\tab) '(#\H #\e)) ; ==> #t)`? You have a weird notion of equal.

Answer (score 1):

```
;; Character -> Boolean
;; is char either #\space, #\tab, or #\newline?
(define (space? char)
  (or (char=? char #\space)
      (char=? char #\tab)
      (char=? char #\newline)))
```

Consider all these cases for the `same?` function:

- both `L1` and `L2` are `null`
- `L1` is `null` and `(car L2)` satisfies `space?`
- both `(car L1)` and `(car L2)` satisfy `space?`
- `(car L1)` satisfies `space?` and `L2` is `null`
- What happens when both `L1` and `L2` are neither `null` nor are `(car L1)` and `(car L2)` `spaces`? You simply compare them. If they're the same - recur. If they're not - return `#false`

Coming up with concrete examples first usually lead to templates like these, from there it's easier to complete the function. Then see if you can simplify.

Comment: What do you mean by `(car L1)` or `(car L2)` being `null`? Do you mean that the list is empty?

Comment: Yes. It's the same as per the [doc](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._null%29%29)s. I was assuming it's common to use `car`, `cdr`, and `null` as opposed to `first`, `rest` and  `empty` in scheme.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the difference between `(car L)` being null and `L` being null. Like the difference between `(empty? (first L))` and `(empty? L)`.

Comment: Sorry, should've been `L` instead of `(car L)`! Edited.

Answer (score -2):

I set your condition like this:

1. two char list must have a #\space or #\tab, or failed.
2. compare the part before #\space or #\tab.

right?

```
#lang racket

(define (same? l1 l2)
  (let loop ([loop_l1 l1]
             [loop_l2 l2]
             [result #f])
    (if (and
         (not (null? loop_l1))
         (not (null? loop_l2)))
        (if
         (or
           (char=? (car loop_l1) #\tab)
           (char=? (car loop_l1) #\space)
           (char=? (car loop_l2) #\tab)
           (char=? (car loop_l2) #\space))
         result
         (if (char=? (car loop_l1) (car loop_l2))
             (loop (cdr loop_l1) (cdr loop_l2) #t)
             #f))
        #f)))

(same? 
 '(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o #\tab #\W #\o #\r #\l #\d)
 '(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o #\space))
;; #t

(same? 
 '(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o #\tab #\W #\o #\r #\l #\d)
 '(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o))
;; #f

(same? 
 '(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o)
 '(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o #\tab #\W #\o #\r #\l #\d))
;; #f

(same? 
 '(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o)
 '(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o))
;; #f

(same? 
 '(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o #\tab #\W #\o #\r #\l #\d)
 '(#\H #\e #\l #\l))
;; #f
```